# Unity - How to Dynamically set LightingSettings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm trying to dynamically change my lighting settings in Unity using the following:

```
Lightmapping.lightingSettings = myLightingSettings;
```

However `Lightmapping` is a class part of `UnityEditor` which means I can't use anything from that namespace in a build (results in a compile error of 'The name 'Lightmapping' does not exist in the current context').

Is there a way to dynamically change the LightingSettings at runtime?

Comment: what exactly you want to change in light settings?

Comment: @MiladQasemi I have a few .lighting files and I literally just want to swap them out programmatically